# How to transform an enumeration of long to a single string with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I am wondering if there is an easy and clean way (one line) to transform an enumeration of long (IEnumerable) to a single string (string) with LINQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the long (integers?) to be comma separated try:

```
string str = string.Join(", ", myLongs.Select(l => l.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for aggregate/fold:

```
var longs = new long[] {3, 2, 1, 0};
var str = longs.Aggregate("", (s, l) => s + l);
// str = "3210"
```

Although I am not quite sure what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(yourIEnumerable, yourDelimiter)
```

Comment: string.Join takes an array, not an IEnumerable, and the delimiter comes first.

Comment: And it takes an array of strings, not longs.